# Why doesn't output refresh automatically on location.hash?

Tags: javascript, hash, location

new location hash doesn't output when clicking on link.

I am at a loss understanding why the browser doesn't output the updated variable.

```
<html>
<body>
<p></p>
<a href="#2019-01">1</a>
<a href="#2019-02">2</a>
</body>
<script>
var p = document.querySelector('p');
p.innerHTML = location.hash; 
</script>
</html>
```

When I click on the first link, the address in the browser changes to #2019-01, but p.innerHTML displays nothing.
I expected it to display #2019-01.

If I hit crtl r, to reload the page, then p.innerHTML displays #2019-01.

Why do I have to force a reload to get the output?
Is there a way to get the updated location.hash value without reloading the page?

Comment: The stuff in between the `script` tag only runs once, when the page loads. If you want to run it again when a button is clicked, you have to call it when the button is clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you create a `showHash` function and then call it immediate when the page loads. Additionally, you can add an event listener to `window.onhashchange` to call the `showHash` function any time the hash changes.

```js
showHash();

function showHash() {
  var p = document.querySelector('p');
  p.innerHTML = location.hash;
}

window.onhashchange = showHash;
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
  <p></p>
  <a href="#2019-01">1</a>
  <a href="#2019-02">2</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked, I tried clicking the check mark to accept your answer, but its not working in my browser.

Comment: It has been marked as accepted, might just be your browser taking a moment to update. Thanks!